# Xcode Lua. Lua file in wrong place

Tags: iphone, xcode, scripting, lua

I have lua working in my iPhone project, but I have one annoying problem.  When I add a new lua file I use xcode to create a default Empty file.  Xcode recognize the ".lua" extension as a source file and places it in my Target's "Compile Sources" folder instead of the "Copy Bundle Resources".

Is there a way to have xcode place the my lua file in the "Copy Bundle Resources", without manually moving it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is odd.  When I create a .lua file as you described, it places it in the Copy Bundle Resources phase.

Do you have some kind of custom specifications installed in Xcode to manage Lua?  It is possible that is an issue with the specification.

Comment: I do have a lua syntax highlighting script in xcode.  That could be marking my script file as a source code file, and moving it to the incorrect location.   I will double check that when I get home.